# Uniform convergence and differentiation proof

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, uniform-convergence

Theorem: Let $f_n:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$, $n=1,2,\ldots$ be differentiable on $[a,b]$.

Suppose:

(i) $(f_n(x))$ converges for some $c \in [a,b]$

(ii) $(f'_n)$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$.

Then $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$, and if $\displaystyle f=\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n$ then $f$ is differentiable with $\displaystyle f'(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f'_n(x)$.

The proof in my lecture note starts like this:

Proof: Fix $x\in[a,b]$. Apply the Mean Value Theorem to $(f_n - f_m)$ to get $(f_n - f_m)(x) - (f_n-f_m)(c) = (x-c)((f'_n - f'_m)(t))$
 for some $t$ between $x$ and $c$.

Then: $\displaystyle\sup_{x\in[a,b]} |f_n(x)-f_m(x)| \le |f_n(c) - f_m(c)| + (b-a)\sup_{t\in[a,b]} |f'_n(t)-f'_m(t)|$.

I do not understand how this last line follows though, in particular how we can have $t\in[a,b]$ when it must be between $x$ and $c$. Btw there could be a mistake there as my lecturer doesn't have great handwriting so please say if you think that is the case.

Comment: $x,c \in [a,b]$ so $t \in [x,c] \subset [a,b]$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I know that, but what if the sup is outside of [x,c]?

Comment: In general for $A \subset B$, $\sup_{x \in A} f(x) \le \sup_{x \in B} f(x)$. This is what is used here.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Ah of course! duh :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you don't understand follows from rearranging the previous line and taking the supremum.  So:
$$(f_n-f_m)(x)-(f_n-f_m)(c) = (x-c)(f'_n - f'_m)(t) $$
Rearranging gives us:
$$(f_n-f_m)(x) = (f_n-f_m)(c) + (x-c)(f'_n - f'_m)(t) $$
Taking the supremum of both sides:
$$\sup_{x\in[a,b]} \left| f_n(x)-f_m(x)\right| = \sup_{x\in[a,b]} \left|f_n(c)-f_m(c)\right| + \sup_{x\in[a,b]}\left|(x-c)(f'_n(t)-f'_m(t))\right| $$
Now, on the right hand side, the first term is independent of $x$ so we can drop the supremum from it.  For the second term the supremum is going to affect $(x-c)$.  The largest this can be is $b-a$ since that's the measure of the interval.  It's also going to affect that $t$ since $t\in[x,c]$, so we can allow the supremum to refer to that explicitly.

So, replacing $(x-c)$ by ($b-a)$ and writing the suprema appropriately we see that the right hand side will never be smaller than the left hand side, but because we've extended $(x-c)$ out to $b-a$ it might be bigger.  So equality becomes inequality and you get
$$\sup_{x\in[a,b]} \left| f_n(x)-f_m(x)\right| \leq \left|f_n(c)-f_m(c)\right| + (b-a)\sup_{t\in[a,b]}\left|(f'_n(t)-f'_m(t))\right| $$

Comment: Thanks. I might just be worrying over nothing but is it completely obvious that you can take sups of both sides when absolute values are involved? In particular because we have a sum in the RHS

Comment: Yes, in fact that makes it easier because you're guaranteed that the supremum of an absolute value cannot be less than zero.  That ensures that you can place the inequality sign in there.  For a counterexample, consider $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (-1-1/n)$

Comment: But if you have A = B + C, the value of x that maximises B may not be the same as that which maximises C. So how can you say that sup B + sup C = sup A?

Comment: in that case you can't, you're right.  But here your B is independent of the supremum you're taking: it's effectively a constant and so the supremum holds.

Comment: Ah ok, it looked like you were using it as a general rule. thanks for helping

Comment: @LTS No problem :)